# CppCheck rule not show #define, comment

Tags: c++, c, cppcheck

I'm create custom rule for cppCheck. When I create rule like not allow #define in project. But --rule=.+ not show #define in my test project. 
Is there any option or flag for cppcheck to show #define in my code ?

my rule file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rule version="1">
       <pattern>#define</pattern>
</rule>
```

my example:

```
#define TEST 1

int main() {
    int a = TEST;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `not show #define` - please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - a minimal reproducible example, including steps on how did you created the custom rule? How did you add the custom rule? On what code did you test? Please including a smallest possible source code of your "test project" where the `#define` doesn't show.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. I have edit my question

Comment: Why on earth would you not allow `#define`? How do you plan to write header guards without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document `writing-rules-2.pdf` at https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/files/Articles/ states: "The Cppcheck data is preprocessed. There are no comments, #define, #include, etc."

As an alternative you can create a XML dump using `cppcheck --dump yourfile.c` and post-process the dump e.g. by a Python script.
The `#define TEST 1` line of your example is then part of the `rawtokens` and `directivelist` section.
Several Cppcheck addons do it this way (e.g. Python MISRA-C addon). See "addons" directory of Cppcheck at GitHub. Within this directory there is also a Python helper script `cppcheckdata.py` which reads a dump file and creates object lists for tokens, functions, etc.